# How to style input text in textbox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to display the text just below, not in the middle of the textbox. How can I do this?

What I have:
[image]

What I want:
[image]

The first is a `textbox`, second is `textblock`

```
<TextBlock
       Height="16"
       MinWidth="150"
       FontFamily="Monospace"
       FontSize="14"
       Text="Search..."
       FontWeight="Normal"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Margin="3 0 0 0"/>
```

All I need is to change `TextBlock -> TextBox` and get the same text display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"` in your search `<TextBox/>`.